# MVC 5 Webpage save button display label

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, view, actionresult

I have a controller with a create ActionResult which saves data in a webform.
When the information in saved in the form i would like to display a label saving the data was saved.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: ofcourse it is possible to do.

Comment: Depends on how you are sending the form data to the action method. If you are using ajax, you can show the message on the success event of the ajax call, If it is a normal form submit, you can redirect to another view and pass a message (in querystring or via TempData) and show the message in the next view (Rendered by the redirect)

Comment: i rendered it on another view. not sure if its the best approach but it works. Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it is possible to do. Something along these lines should work fine. You can apply the same principles for an error message. The reason i put the if to check whether the view bag is null is because that bootstrap class will put an empty green block on the screen if its null

razor view

```
@if(ViewBag.Success != null){
    <p class="alert alert-success">@ViewBag.Success</p>
}
```

mvc Post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(FormData fd){
     //... save your form
     ViewBag.Success = "You have successfully saved something."
     Return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi Harry, Thats works but iam using a viewmodel to bind to the form and it now gets and error when i try and bind to my dropdown list.

Comment: i was using the return type redirectoaction